# Removing edges from WireframeGeometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am experimenting with THREE.js and am trying to implement a WireframeGeometry for a plane and remove the diagonal lines so that it looks like a grid of squares instead of a grid of squares with diagonal lines running through them.

Is it possible ot remove individual lines from a wireframe geometry that comes with THREE.js?

```
let matLine, wireframe
  let geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 80, 80, 80, 80 )

  const geometry = new WireframeGeometry2( geo )

  matLine = new LineMaterial( {

    color: 0x4080ff,
    linewidth: 6, // in pixels
    //resolution:  // to be set by renderer, eventually
    dashed: false

  } )

  wireframe = new Wireframe( geometry, matLine )
  wireframe.computeLineDistances()
  wireframe.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 )
  wireframe.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
  scene.add( wireframe )
```

Comment: WebGL faces can only be rendered as lots of small triangles, so the PlaneGeometry creates a plane with lots of triangles. If you want a grid of squares, you'll have to either use `GridHelper`, or draw the grid of lines yourself as demonstrated [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_buffergeometry_lines_indexed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three.js faces are triangles and WireframeGeometry draws lines on the edges of faces. It's not possible to make a `grid of squares` with WireframeGeometry.

If you only need the grid for a Plane, you could use GridHelper:
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=grid#api/en/helpers/GridHelper

But it works for only a plane and not other geometry.